# S3-imported images occasionally corrupted: renders on Chrome, but not Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, image-processing, amazon-s3, corrupt

One part of our app is involved in re-hosting remote images onto our own S3 bucket and displaying the results on our site. Occasionally in ~3% of cases, the image import will result in an image that Firefox believes is corrupt, resulting in an `Image corrupt or truncated.` error in the console. But the image renders in Chrome perfectly fine, *unless* in a Print Page dialog, then it exhibits the same behavior as Firefox. It seems to work on Safari in all cases.

The problem persists when I re-import the same file onto S3 or even another hosting site like imgur.com. I created a fiddle where you can test the load behavior for yourself using a known corrupted image.

https://jsfiddle.net/ysLa27bo/1/

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-1')
obj = s3.bucket(MY_BUCKET_NAME).object(MY_S3_DIR_PATH)
obj.put(body: open(REMOTE_PATH_TO_IMAGE), acl: 'public-read')
```

Above is my S3 import code using the AWS-SDK-S3 ruby gem ran through a Sidekiq worker in a Rails 5+ environment. I should stress that this corrupted image issue is intermittent; 97% of my other imports work perfectly fine in all browsers and settings, so I don't think it's an issue with my code.

My best guess is that the image corrupts at one of two steps: at `open()` (reading the remote image url) or the part where we import to S3. Since the images can load perfectly fine in Chrome, I think it's more likely to be a problem at the latter step. Is it possible that Sidekiq shutting down as a result of an app deploy/restart (Heroku) might corrupt the file import somehow? Just a guess.

My questions are: Why does this happen? How do I ensure image corruption doesn't occur when I import to S3? Is there any way for me to automatically check the image's validity post-import, short of running a Firefox-driven Selenium instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to prevent further instances of this happening by specifically including the `content-type` header in my `obj.put` call. Specifically, that line now looks something like:

`obj.put(body: open(REMOTE_PATH_TO_IMAGE), acl: 'public-read', content_type: "image/jpeg")`

It's interesting to note that setting the content type for a corrupted image *after* it's been imported to S3 will not de-corrupt the image. So the issue isn't that S3 isn't responding with valid headers for the image, but that the corruption occurs at the time of import. I had a strong hunch at the time, but this gave me more clarity into the issue.